# How to validate activerecord fields on request in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is too generic, I'm developing a shopping cart in which I need to validate user address field when user is about to checkout request. I know there is `on::create` method. Apart from that is there any thing that can validate on Controller::action happens?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is something usually referred to as `Form Objects`.

Basically, you define an object (a Class) which matches the data returned from your form, and you use normal ActiveRecord validations against that object when the form is submitted.

There is a great RailsCast that runs through exactly how this works and how to implement it. Granted the Rails version is a little old, but the concept is the same. Have a look here - http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects

Another good article on the same concept was written by ThoughtBot - https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects